# Einstein bot builder - binding variable not working

Tags: einstein

I have one chat bot that I want to display the actual value of the variable, but its displaying it as a text. According to trailhead this is the right approach to do so.

This variable: Looked_Up_Case__c is being retrieved at a flow. There I query for the Subject and the Status of the case. The flow is working properly.

[image: Dialogs]

[image: Variable declaration]

[image: Result]

Comment: Are you looking to retrieve `Status` and `Subject` from a custom object (`Looked_Up_Case__c`) or is this a variable? What Trailhead are you following?

Comment: Hi there, ive edited the post. Here is the trailhead. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-an-einstein-bot/write-bot-conversations-using-slots-and-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce displays the variable API name when they are null (not very good in my opinion but that how it currently works).
I ended up creating one variable per text instead of using the object.field.

Answer (score 0):

If the bot doesn't have access to the object fields you would also receive a response message with the variables name instead of the value. In this case, edit the permission set called "sfdc.chatbot.service.permset" and set the object and its fields to read access.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).